# Running mbunit test cases from commandline

Tags: c#-4.0, mbunit

I have to execute the mbunit test cases by passing the dll to gallio.echo. ( or using anything that may execute test cases through commandline and generates xml report ) 
My requirement is my dll depends upon the functions inside another dll so do i need to pass both dll while exceuting testing.

currently I m getting issues while using gallio.echo with dll as argument.

suggest a way to test dll through commandline.

regards
priya

Comment: What sort of issues are you getting? Is there an error message?

Comment: hi rob, currently i m getting issue " no test found "..........moreover a bad image error is thrown by gallio saying the image is not loaded properly.

Comment: actual error : Execute
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Utility, Version=12.0.121.2201, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
FileName: Utility, Version=12.0.121.2201, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
FusionLog: WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
HResult: -2147024885

Answer (score 0):

Usually an issue with 32 / 64 bit.  Make sure your Gallio Installation matches the assembly (if gallio install is 64 bit and dll is 32 bit, it won't work.